# Advice on how to increase storage on a full MD3200i

Tags: raid, network-attached-storage, storage

We have a Dell MD3200i with all 12 bays full, running 12x1TB 7200 RPM HDDs including 1 hot spare in a RAID5 config. We are going to be at capacity in the next few years, so I'm looking to provide the best options for an upgrade.

I'd like to purchase an MD1200, attach it to the MD3200i via SAS, purchase 14-24x4TB 7200RPM HDDs, and rebuild the RAID from RAID5 to RAID1+0. This gives us a lot of flexibility (24 bays, rather than 12), is surprisingly cost-effective, upgrades us to more storage than we will need for the next few years, and give me peace of mind knowing I am off a RAID5 created who-knows-when.

What would be the best, safest, way to accomplish this? My thinking is:

1. backup entire existing MD3200i
2. remove all drives in existing MD3200i and replace with new 4TB drives
3. attach the new new MD1200 via SAS, add in additional 4TB drives
4. Build the RAID to 1+0
5. reinstate the data?

Is this how you would go about doing this? I feel like I'm missing something and as I have never done this before, I'd like to ask your opinions on how this should best be done.

Comment: Chris, we're voting to move this over to the enterprise-server-focused StackExchange site: ServerFault. It'll be more likely to get good answers over there.

Comment: Feel free to delete one of these - Apologies, i recreated it before I realized that it was going to be posted over here automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating a RAID on the MD3 is a pretty reliable process, a good backup is mandatory anyway. You don't need to restore the data afterwards, if nothing goes wrong all will still be in place. Make sure you verify the array before you start migration to make sure all yet undiscovered read errors get cleaned out. Updating obsolete firmware should also be done.

With these large and slow drives, a rebuild after failure will take quite a while. RAID 10 is probably the only somewhat safe way to go, RAID 5 and even RAID 6 pretty much prohibitive.

Do make sure you've got regular and reliable backups in the future and you're scrubbing the array on a monthly basis - this significantly reduces the risk of running into an error when rebuilding.

Comment: Fantastic, I will definitely keep the scrubbing in mind going forward, and remember to verify the array before I start migration for the undiscovered read error cleaning.